# Get resource value type

Tags: c#, .net

I am using ResourceSet to access assembly resource files. Some of the resource values in these files are null. How can I get the expected resource value type when the value is null?

Here is the code i use:

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(fileName);
foreach (var resourceName in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
    using (ResourceSet reader = new ResourceSet(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)))
    {                     
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
        { ... }
    }
```

Comment: `typeof(YourResourcesManager).GetProperty("Name").PropertyType`

Comment: I am not using a resource manager. I am reading assembly resources from an external application with the ResourceSet class.

Comment: Post the code then

Comment: using (ResourceSet reader = new ResourceSet(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName)))
                {                     
                    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
                    { ... }
                }

Comment: Please add it to the question